# Communicate with Rar.exe in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, interactive, rar, pexpect

From a Python script I want to create a RAR file. I will need to communicate with Rar.exe because I only want the first RAR volume from a multi-volume archive set, nothing more. The `-vp` switch makes sure `Create next volume ? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll` is asked after each volume. The first time this question pops up, I want to answer No. How do I accomplish this?

I've been reading and trying a lot of things and I found out something like this can be accomplished with [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect). I've been trying the two different Windows ports: [wexpect](https://web.archive.org/web/20090205040528/http://sage.math.washington.edu:80/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/) and [winpexpect](https://github.com/geertj/winpexpect). The result is that my script will hang. No RAR file is created. This is my code:

```
import wexpect
import sys

rarexe = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
args = ['a', '-vp', '-v2000000b', 'only_first.rar', 'a_big_file.ext']

child = wexpect.spawn(rarexe, args)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
index = child.expect(["Create next volume ? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll", 
        wexpect.EOF, wexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=10)
if index == 0:
     child.sendline("N")
else:
     print('error')
```

Other approaches are welcome too.

Comment: On what line does it hang?

Comment: @f13o: In the above code it hangs on `child = wexpect.spawn(rarexe, args)` and in wexpect it hangs on `msg = GetMessage(0, 0, 0)`. [That is this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem has two parts.

As betontalpfa indicated, I must use his [version of wexpect](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect). It can be installed easily:

```
pip install wexpect
```

The `expect_exact` documentation of [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect_exact) explains that it uses plain string matching instead of compiled regular expressions patterns in the list. This means the parameters must be properly escaped or the `expect_exact` method must be used instead of `expect`. It gave me this working code:

```
import wexpect
import sys

rarexe = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe"
args = ['a', '-vp', '-v2000000b', 'only_first.rar', 'a_big_file.ext']

child = wexpect.spawn(rarexe, args)
# child.logfile = sys.stdout
rar_prompts = [
        "Create next volume \? \[Y\]es, \[N\]o, \[A\]ll",
        "\[Y\]es, \[N\]o, \[A\]ll, n\[E\]ver, \[R\]ename, \[Q\]uit",
        wexpect.EOF, wexpect.TIMEOUT]
index = child.expect(rar_prompts, timeout=8)

while index < 2:
        # print(child.before)
        if index == 0:
                print("No next volume")
                child.sendline("N")
        elif index == 1:
                print("Overwriting existing volume")
                child.sendline("Y")
        index = child.expect(rar_prompts, timeout=8)
else:
        print('Index: %d' % index)
        if index == 2:
                print("Success!")
        else:
                print("Time out!")
```

And the output gives:

```
Overwriting existing volume
No next volume
Index: 2
Success!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, because there are several (buggy) version of wexpect on the web.

Check out of [my variant](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/blob/master/wexpect.py), which is a copy of an instance, which worked for me.

This can be installed using

`pip install wexpect`

Comment: I see you got down voted. I just tried it out on the provided script but it doesn't work for me either. After the time-out it shows `Create next volume ? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll error`. It is an improvement on my past experience since I don't recall seeing `error` printed. Is it an issue with wexpect or my script above? I used RAR 5.50 x64 now.

Comment: Thanks for, not just dropping a down vote. When do you get this message? (During installaion?  During runnin (at start, while waiting prompt)?) Can you post it as new issue with more details (https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues) ?

Comment: The message is the output of the program in the question. There I display `error` myself after the question prompt of rar.exe that wexpect didn't detect. I'm running it on Windows.

Comment: Your program's error maybe caused by the the stderr handling error of wexpect, which is a known issue. https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/issues/2